# Finding type of a property, having domain class and property path

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

Having a grails domain class, how to find the type of a property having its path. For example, suppose following classes:

```
class Contract {
    Client owner
}

class Client {
    String title
}
```

Following code is in a controller :

```
DefaultGrailsDomainClass domainClass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass("pkg.Contract")
```

Now having the Contract DefaultGrailsDomainClass and **`"owner.title"`**, is it possible to find title's type? (Which should be String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is too simple:

```
domainClass.getPropertyByName("owner.title")
```